# Getting data from Mongodb Atlas in the console when running npm start , but cannot get the URL

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, axios

I am trying to set up a Vue js page to list the data from MongoDB Atlas.
My Node JS server is connecting fine, and getting the API (Documents) listed.

See the code here that is working, but I am not able to get the URL for my localhost.
The localhost:4000/whatever-needs-to-be-here??? is all giving an error of can't get data.

The port it is listening at is 4000

I have axios on a page trying to get data, but I am not sure what URL to enter in the axios get('????') as my local url is not working.

What am I missing to have the data display in the browser?

````
    npm start
    
    > my-view-app@0.1.0 start /Users/macbookpro/my-vue-app-03-4
    > node server.js
    
    Server listening at 4000
    
    This is what I get in the console when running npm start.
    
    Also, the cluster name is clusterdives,  the database name is: dive_db, the collection name is dives.
    
    ```
    (node:2276) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
    [MongoDB connection] SUCCESS
    [
      {
        _id: 5f9ca2dd9a1d712bd137aa73,
        dive_number: 1,
        dive_date: 2015-06-06T04:00:00.000Z,
        dive_location: 'Lake Phoenix, Rawlings, Va',
        dive_country: 'United States',
        dive_description: 'Dive number 4 of open water training',
        dive_note: 'long note and description of the dive. This is where we write down memorable moments of the dive, prior to the dive, during the dive and after the dive.',
        dive_duration: { dive_duration_value: 45, dive_duration_unit: 'min' },
        dive_depth: { dive_depth_value: 50, dive_depth_unit: 'ft' }
      },
      {
        _id: 5fa2142f137e530a5a4a7cf7,
        dive_number: '2',
        dive_date: '2015-06-06T04:00:00.000+00:00',
        dive_location: ' Lake Phoenix, Rawlings, Va',
        dive_country: 'United States',
        dive_description: 'Dive number 4 of open water training',
        dive_note: 'long note and description of the dive. This is where we write down mem',
        dive_duration: { dive_duration_value: '45', dive_duration_unit: 'min' },
        dive_depth: { dive_depth_value: '50', dive_depth_unit: 'ft' }
      }
    ]
````

This is the scrip section in the Mainlist vue component/page.

```
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
      name: 'Mainlist',
      data() {
        return {
          dive_db: [],
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        axios.get('**THIS IS WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR**').then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.dive_db = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
      }
    }
    </script>
```